# 2 arrays matchings , transformation in arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

is it possible to compare 2 arrays and make object for each item with string value and boolean:

```js
const array = ["ABC", "BCA", "CDA", "APA"];
const array2 = ["ABC", "APA"];

array2 = [{
    value: "ABC",
    matched: true,
  },
  {
    value: "BCA",
    matched: false,
  },
  {
    value: "CDA",
    matched: false,
  },
  {
    value: "APA",
    matched: true,
  },
];
```

Comment: what if you have one more not matching item in `array2`? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```js
let array = ["ABC", "BCA", "CDA", "APA"]
let array2 = ["ABC", "APA"]

const output = array.map((item) => {
  let isFound = array2.includes(item);
  return { value: item, matched: isFound };
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)